# Linear algebra hw! Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, proof-verification

Let $T : V -> V$ be a linear transformation where V is a nite dimensional vector space. If rank(T) = rank$(T^2)$, prove that image(T)$\cap$Ker(T) = {0}. 
I have to give this hw to my prof this afternoon but till now I dunno how to work on it. Can anyone help me please, thanks a lot.

So far I got:
Let $V \in img(T) \cap ker(T) \neq 0$
=> There exist some non-zero $x \in V s.t T(x) = 0$ and $T^2 (x) = T(x) = 0$
We know that $ ker(T) \subseteq ker(T^2)$ 
And sice $x \neq ker (T)$ but $x \in ker (T^2)$
We have $Nullity (T) \le Nullity (T^2)$
then will next I can do?

Comment: What are your ideas so far. Have you tried anything?

Comment: what would be your first step to do this? may be "let $a\in Image(T)\cap Ker(T)$"??? what would be next step?

Comment: I still have nothing on my head, im thinking about if $(T^2)$ = 0?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the image and kernel of $T$ have a non-trivial intersection. Let $v_1$ be a non-zero vector in this intersection.  Add the vectors $v_2,\dots,v_n$ so that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of the image of $T$. The image of $T^2$ is spanned by $\{T v_1,\dots,T v_n \}= \{0, T v_2,\dots,T v_n\}$.

What may we conclude about the dimension of the image of (i.e. the rank of) $T^2$?

---

Alternatively:

Suppose that $T$ and $T^2$ have the same rank.  We can find a set of vectors $x_1\dots,x_n$ for which $\{Tx_1,\dots,Tx_n\}$ form a basis of the image of $T$. We note that $T(\{Tx_1,\dots,Tx_n\}) =$ $\{T^2x_1,\dots,T^2x_n\}$ must span the image of $T^2$.  Since there are exactly as many vectors as the dimension of the image of $T^2$ (which is equal to the dimension of the image of $T$), we note that this forms a basis.

It follows that the restriction of $T$ to the image of $T$ is an isomorphism. What may we conclude about $\ker (T\mid_{x \in \operatorname{Image}(T)})$?